# Lebesgue Decomposition of Lebesgue Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $m$ be the Lebesgue measure and $v$ be the counting measure on the interval $[0,1]$. I know that the Lebesgue decomposition theorem does not hold true for $v$ wrt $m$ on this interval in the sense that $v$ cannot be split as follows:

$$
\nu=\nu_a+\nu_s,\space\space\nu_a(E)=\int_E(fdm),\space\space 
\nu_s(X-X_s)=m(X_s)=0\space\space\space
$$

My problem is showing that the Lebesgue measure has no decomposition wrt $v$ in this same sense. I'm under the impression that I just need to pick a subset of $[0,1]$ that isn't Lebesgue measurable but that doesn't seem to be working. Any thoughts?

Comment: The counting measure on $[0,1]$ is not $\sigma$-finite.  This could be a real obstacle.

Comment: I figured as much, I'm just having trouble finding a direct way to show why.

Answer (score 2):

Solution that I've come up with. Thanks for the advice!

Suppose such a decomposition $m=m_a+m_s$ exists. Then $\mu(\mathscr{X}_s)=0$ implies $\mathscr{X}_s=\emptyset$.

Pick $x\in E$. Then $m(x)=\int_xfd\mu$. Since $m(\{x\})=0$, it follows that 
$$0=\int_xfd\mu=f(x)\mu(x)\implies f(x)=0$$
Since $m(E)=\int_Efd\mu$, we must have $m(E)=0$. Thus, for $E\subseteq[0,1]$, we have $m(E)=0 \implies m([0,1])=0$, so we get a contradiction.

Comment: Don't write plain text in mathmode. If you must, use \textrm or something of the sort. It looks awful and is very hard to read.

Comment: I've fixed the formatting a little. Some hints to improve the answer: the mention of $E$ is superfluous. You can just forgo it completely and just work with $[0,1]$. Also $\rightarrow\leftarrow$ is not a notation for contradiction I'm familiar with, so I've changed it for a simple (worded) statement (so that others unfamiliar with it will have no problem understanding this). Otherwise, nice work.

Comment: Thanks for the editing help. I'm new to typing up my solutions and appreciate all the tips I can get. And thanks for the earlier hint, too.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: suppose that there is such a decomposition. Consider two cases: when $f$ has countable support and when it doesn't.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by countable support. In class my professor only ever mentioned compact support and we didn't go into detail regarding the subject.

Comment: @user110711: I mean that there exists a countable set $S$ such that $f(x)=0$ if $x\notin S$. In general, (a) support of a function is a set in its domain outside which it is trivial. In case of measurable functions, it means the set outside which the function is zero.

Comment: Ok, I think I found a solution. Thanks for the help. I'm posting it below.